# Unusual Zip File Unpackaging Errors

Tags: python, module, zip

I've been trying to script controls for my keyboard and mouse in python on **OSX Yosemite (10.10.3)**. I've found lots of answers regarding different third party packages I can download and use (PyUserInput, PyAutoGUI, etc). When I attempt to unpack about half of the required zip files I receive the following error:**"Unable to expand "filename.zip" into "Downloads". (Error 1 - Operation not permitted.) "** This has happened with the following zipped files: "pyobjc-framework-Quartz-3.0.4.tar.gz", "pyobjc-core-3.0.4.tar.gz", "setuptools-18.1.zip", yet I had no problem with other files of similar type. If anyone can provide clarity that would be great.

Comment: It means that your archieve utility doesnt like the fact that code is stored inside of the archives

Comment: Wrong forum; consider moving it to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Is there better software I should use to unpackage it?